# Making a class abstract in Python

Tags: python, abstract-class

I was working on making `EFeatureObjective` as abstract, I knew I can implement a class and just make `calculate_feature_scores` as abstract but things I did -

```
class EFeatureObjective(bluepyopt.objectives.Objective):

    """EPhys feature objective"""

    def __init__(self, name, features=None):
        """Constructor
        Args:
            name (str): name of this object
            features (list of eFeatures): features used in the Objective
        """

        super(EFeatureObjective, self).__init__(name)
        self.name = name
        self.features = features

    def calculate_feature_scores(self, responses):
        """Calculate the scores for the individual features"""

        scores = []
        for feature in self.features:
            scores.append(feature.calculate_score(responses))

        return scores


class SingletonObjective(EFeatureObjective):

    """Single EPhys feature"""

    def __init__(self, name, feature):
        """Constructor
        Args:
            name (str): name of this object
            features (EFeature): single eFeature inside this objective
        """

        super(SingletonObjective, self).__init__(name, [feature])

    def calculate_score(self, responses):
        """Objective score"""

        return self.calculate_feature_scores(responses)[0]

    def __str__(self):
        """String representation"""

        return '( %s )' % self.features[0]
```

- I made `EFeatureObjective` as abstract using `ABC = abc.ABCMeta('ABC', (object,), {'__slots__': ()})` and had

  ```
      def calculate_feature_scores(self, responses):                                   
           pass
  ```

  like

  ```
   import abc                                                                           

   ABC = abc.ABCMeta('ABC', (object,), {'__slots__': ()})                               


   class EFeatureObjective(bluepyopt.objectives.Objective, ABC):                           

        """EPhys feature objective"""                                                       
        def __init__(self, name, features=None):                                            
              """Constructor                                                                  

              Args:                                                                           
              name (str): name of this object                                             
              features (list of eFeatures): features used in the Objective                
              """                                                                             

              super(EFeatureObjective, self).__init__(name)                                   
              self.name = name                                                                
              self.features = features                                                        

        @abc.abstractmethod                                                                 
        def calculate_feature_scores(self, responses):    
            pass


   class SingletonObjective(EFeatureObjective):
         .........
         def calculate_feature_scores(self, responses):                                   
             """Calculate the scores for the individual features"""                       

             scores = []                                                                  
             for feature in self.features:                                                
             scores.append(feature.calculate_score(responses))                        

             return scores
  ```

  I then implemented this method in `SingletonObjective`, the problem is syntax wise can this be implemented? The `features` aren't available in `SingletonObjective`. Basically `EFeatureObjective` operates on `(list of eFeatures)` and `SingletonObjective` operates on `single eFeature inside this objective`.
- I then called the abstract class `EFeatureObjective` abstract method `calculate_feature_scores` inside `SingletonObjective` like

  ```
   def calculate_feature_scores(self, responses):
       super(SingletonObjective, self).calculate_feature_scores(responses)
  ```

  but then

  ```
   def calculate_score(self, responses):                                               
           """Objective score"""                                                           

           return self.calculate_feature_scores(responses)[0]
  ```

  the index would error.

I have spent quiet a while on this, and now I want `EFeatureObjective` be abstract without creating a class working w/ different Python versions. Appreciate any answers.

Comment: Are you a java programmer by chance?  I think one of the things about Python is that a lot of this is most likely unnecessary and there is likely a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. Why *aren't* you using the `@abstractclass` or `@abstractmethod` decorators?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a class that you cannot instantiate but can subclass, then here is a way to do so:

```
class BaseClass(object):
  def __new__(cls):
    ''' If this is not a subclass being instanciated, then raise an error '''
    if cls is BaseClass:
      raise TypeError('Cannot instantiate this')
    return object.__new__(cls)

   AbstractMethod1 = None

   def __init_subclass__(cls):
     ''' Anytime subclasses are created, make sure they have the right methods '''
     if cls.AbstractMethod1 is None:
       raise TypeError('All subclasses of `base` must define `AbstractMethod1`')
```